# Be $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ functions. Suppose that $y=f(x)$ iff $x=g(y)$. Prove that $f$ is invertible and $g=f^{-1}$

Tags: functions, solution-verification, set-theory

I want to prove the exercise of the statement, so what I am trying to do is to prove that the inverse of $f$ is a function.

1.Let $(a,b)\in f$ then $b=f(a)$ and by hypothesis $a=g(b)$, this means $(b,a)\in g$, but by definition $g=f^{-1}$ then $(b,a)\in f^{-1}$

2. Let $(b, a_1), (b, a_2)\in f^{-1}$ such that $a=g(b)$ how $f^{-1}=g$,as stated above, then $a=f^{-1}(b)$, this means $f^{-1}(b)=a_1$ and $f^{-1}(b)=a_2$, then $a_1=a_2$ and $f^{-1}$ is a function. $f$ is invertible

My attempt was something along these lines, but I'm not quite sure, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you are trying to prove some function $g$ is the inverse to some function $f$, you don't use the symbol $f^{-1}$, because this implies $f$ has an inverse, which is exactly what you are trying to prove.

When, you say, in (1) and other places,

> by definition $g = f^{-1}$

This is what you are proving! It isn't "by definition".
When writing a proof, you should have very clearly in mind what are the definitions of the objects involved and what are your hypotheses. You have to make sure you know where you are using them in your proof.

I don't know how you are defining inverses, but if it were me doing this and I had the following definition:

*Definition*: A function $f : A \to B$ is *invertible* if it is injective and surjective.

I would do something like this:

Let $b \in B$. Since $g$ is a function, there exists $a \in A$ such that $a = g(b)$. But, by hypothesis, this implies $b = f(a)$. So $f$ is surjective.

Let $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1) = f(a_2) \in B$. Since $g$ is a function, we get $g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2))$. However, by hypothesis we have $g(f(a_1)) = a_1$ and $g(f(a_2)) = a_2$. So $a_1 = a_2$ and f is injective.

Now we now $f$ is invertible, i.e., there exists $f^{-1} : B \to A$. We must prove that $g = f^{-1}$. We will do this proving that $g(b) = f^{-1}(b)$ for every $b \in B$. For every $b \in B$, we know, since $f$ is surjective, that there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Hence:
$$
g(b) = g(f(a)) = a = f^{-1}(f(a)) = f^{-1}(b).
$$

*Remark*: The condition $y = f(x)$ if, and only if, $x = g(y)$ is often refered to as $g$ being both the *left and right inverses* of $f$.
A *left inverse* of $f : A \to B$ is a function $g : A \to B$ that satisfies $g(f(a)) = a$ for all $a \in A$ (see how $g$ is positioned to the left of $f$). A *right inverse* of $f : A \to B$ is a function $g: B \to A$ such that $f(g(b)) = b$ for all $b \in B$ (see how, now, $g$ is positioned to the right of $f$).

Comment: Your help is really valuable!